# Os.remove(file) Access is denied?

Tags: python

Code:

```py
import os

user = os.getlogin()

paths = [
    rf"C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp"
]

for file in paths:
    if os.path.exists(file):
        try:
            os.remove(file)
            print("OK", file)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Fail", file, e)
```

I have more paths but this is an example, for some reason I am getting the ERROR:
**Access is denied: 'C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Temp'**

I am running the python script as administrator in command prompt.

Comment: Is that a directory? If its empty, `os.rmdir`, otherwise `shutil.rmtree` (or not, seems like deleting everything in Temp could have negative consequences for things that are temprorary but still in use).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I would go about solving this:

1. Reading the documentation for os.remove() ( ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove )

`If path is a directory, an IsADirectoryError is raised. Use rmdir() to remove directories`

If C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Temp" is a directory than you should modify your code to use rmdir().

2. Reading the documentation for os.remove() ( ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove )

`On Windows, attempting to remove a file that is in use causes an exception to be raised;`

I would check to make sure C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Temp" isn't in use by another process before deleting it.